# I am getting an index out of range error from the data received from the API, how can I solve it?

Tags: swift, api, uitableview, mvvm, outofrangeexception

This fetch data https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/(id)/ id (1,2,3,4,5....) When I click on cells in the table view, I get information in some cells and index errors in others.

**DetailViewController** func ConfigureView()

```
private func configureView() {
        viewModel?.fetchPokemonDetails(completion: { [weak self] in
            guard let self = self else { return }
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self.nameLabel.text = "Name: \(self.viewModel?.name ?? "")"
                self.abilitiesNameLabel.text = "Abilities: \(self.viewModel?.abilities?[0].ability?.name ?? "")"
                if let ability = self.viewModel?.abilities?[1] { // this line I wanted to use if but it didn't work
                    self.abilitiesNameLabel2.text = "Abilities: \(ability.ability?.name ?? "")" // this line
                }
                
                self.typeLabel.text = "Type: \(self.viewModel?.types?[1].type?.name ?? "")" // sometimes it gives error here every time index out of range error
                self.statLabel.text = "Stat: \(self.viewModel?.stats?[0].baseStat ?? 0)"
                
                
                if let imageURL = self.viewModel?.imageURL {
                    self.imageView.sd_setImage(with: imageURL)
                }
            }
        })
    }
```

[image]

**DetailViewModel**

```
var abilities: [Ability]?
    var stats: [Stat]?
    var types: [TypeElement]?
    
    var pokemonId: String
    let apiService: PokeAPIService
    var name: String?
    var imageURL: URL?
    
    // MARK: - Initializers
    init(pokemonId: String,name: String?,imageURL: URL?,apiService: PokeAPIService) {
        self.pokemonId = pokemonId
        self.apiService = apiService
        self.imageURL = imageURL
        self.name = name
    }
    
    // MARK: - Public Methods
    
    func fetchPokemonDetails(completion: @escaping () -> Void) {
        apiService.getPokemon(by: pokemonId) { [weak self] response in
            guard let self = self else { return }
            self.name = response.name
            self.abilities = response.abilities
            self.types = response.types
            self.stats = response.stats
            if let urlString = response.sprites?.other?.officialArtwork?.frontDefault {
                self.imageURL = URL(string: urlString)
            }
            completion()
        }
    }
```

*I tried to do it as if let, I searched on the internet and stackoverflow, but when I examined it with breakpoint, it kept giving the same error.*

Comment: Why are you using 1 instead of 0 ? Do you need the second element of your collection? Btw you can use a safe subscript to return an optional element

Comment: `extension Collection {` `subscript(safe index: Index) -> Element? {` `indices.contains(index) ? self[index] : nil` `}` `}`

Comment: I need 0 and 1, that is, 2 items in the abilities section, when I add an extension and use it, do I make a mistake when calling the index side, the data does not come. How can I integrate and use it? I don't understand the logic :( ?

Comment: If the data doesn’t “come” it is probably returning nil in other words there is no second element for that collection

Comment: If you need up to 3 abilities you can use `viewModel?.abilities?.prefix(3)`. This will return the first 3 abilities of your collection or less.

Comment: Thank you very much I figured thanks a lot 